# What is the difference between socat and agetty?

Tags: virtualization

I am trying to setup [virtio-serial](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Virtio-serial_API) to communicate between a virtual machine and its host. For this, I am following the instructions given here:

- [Using virtio serial to communicate](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/VirtioSerial)

I understand that there is a port on the host at `tmp/foo` on the host which is exposed as a special character device at `/dev/hvc0` on the guest. The instruction manual asks to use `socat` on the host and `agetty` on the guest to spawn the console ports.

However, on using `agetty`, I do not get any console port, whereas, on using `socat` on the guest as well, I can communicate with the host.

I would like to know what are the primary differences between `socat` and `agetty` and whether this is the correct way to use socat, considering `/dev/hvc0` is a special character device.

I have given a look at the manual pages of both and would like a detailed description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Socat is a command line based utility that establishes two bidirectional byte streams and transfers data between them. Because the streams can be constructed from a large set of different types of data sinks and sources, and because lots of address options may be applied to the streams, socat can be used for many different purposes.<sup>[nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-tcp-port-forwarding/)</sup>

socat can do serial line stuff, and it can do fairly advanced functionality, like having multiple clients listen on a port, or reusing connections.  The life cycle of a socat instance typically consists of four phases.

- In the init phase, the command line options are parsed and logging is
  initialized.
- During the open phase, socat opens the first address and afterwards
  the second address. These steps are usually blocking; thus,
  especially for complex address types like socks, connection requests
  or authentication dialogs must be completed before the next step is
  started.
- In the transfer phase, socat watches both streams' read and write
  file descriptors via select() , and, when data is available on one
  side and can be written to the other side, socat reads it, performs
  newline character conversions if required, and writes the data to the
  write file descriptor of the other stream, then continues waiting for
  more data in both directions.
- When one of the streams effectively reaches EOF, the closing phase
  begins. Socat transfers the EOF condition to the other stream, it
  tries to shutdown only its write stream, giving it a chance to
  terminate gracefully. For a defined time socat continues to transfer
  data in the other direction, but then closes all remaining channels
  and terminates.

agetty opens a tty port, prompts for a login name and invokes the `/bin/login` command. It is normally invoked by `init(8)`.  agetty has several non-standard features that are useful for hard-wired and for dial-in lines:<sup>[ManPage](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_agetty.htm)</sup>

- Adapts the tty settings to parity bits and to erase, kill,
  end-of-line and uppercase characters when it reads a login name. The
  program can handle 7-bit characters with even, odd, none or space
  parity, and 8-bit characters with no parity. The following special
  characters are recognized: @ and Control-U (kill); #, DEL and back
  space (erase); carriage return and line feed (end of line).
- Optionally deduces the baud rate from the CONNECT messages produced
  by Hayes(tm)-compatible modems.
- Optionally does not hang up when it is given an already opened line
  (useful for call-back applications).
- Optionally does not display the contents of the /etc/issue file.
- Optionally displays an alternative issue file instead of /etc/issue.
- Optionally does not ask for a login name.
- Optionally invokes a non-standard login program instead of
  /bin/login.
- Optionally turns on hard-ware flow control
- Optionally forces the line to be local with no need for carrier
  detect.
- Supports ringback, if desired. The actual procedure that getty uses
  is as follows: Initially, getty parses its command line. If no errors
  are found, and the tty type from the command line is set to "unknown"
  (the default value), or not set, getty checks for the tty type in
  /etc/ttytype if the program was compiled with TTYTYPE defined. If a
  tty type is found, either on the command line or in the /etc/ttytype
  file, then it is placed into the TERM environment variable. Next,
  getty scans the defaults file, normally /etc/default/getty, to
  determine certain runtime values (/etc/conf.getty if compiled with
  FSSTND option). The values in the defaults file (whose compiled-in
  name can be altered with the optional -d defaults_file argument) take
  precedence to those on the command line. Getty then opens the port
  for reading and writing, and disables stdio buffering. If an
  initialization was specified, it is performed.

<sup>Extra Sources: [Socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html), [agetty MP](http://trinityhome.org/manpages/man8/agetty.8.html)</sup>

Comment: I would appreciate a more detailed explaination, Mitch.

Comment: I have an important task to finish at work, but I will.

Comment: I have added more detail.  I hope that's sufficient enough.

Comment: Let me know if this explanation is sufficient.  Thanks

Comment: I am afraid I do not get a console to login when I am using socat to communicate between the host and a guest virtual machine, which I don't think are socks address. Can you please explain why this is happening or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try this.  You can connect your current terminal emulator to the console: `socat -,raw,echo=0,escape=0x1c tcp:127.0.0.1:20000`
The escape 0x1C is Ctrl-\; it allows you to escape from socat.